# Find a specific kind of string in CSV using VBScript

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have a question because I cannot figure out how to use the patterns in VBScript.
I have a CSV, first line is a name, the second one will contain an "xml" so to say, that I have to search in it for a specific string. I cannot convert it to XML and search the node because the node is dynamic.

The string I am looking for is "ABC12345", it will always have the same 3 characters "ABC" at the beginning and 5 random numbers after the ABC.

So I need a script that will open up a CSV, and output another CSV with the first line with the name and the second will be the specific string I mentioned earlier.

So far I have found this:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "^[1-9]...GRP"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Test.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
    Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)

    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each strMatch In colMatches
            WScript.Echo strSearchString
        Next
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
```

But I didn't find out how to output another CSV and find the string like above.

Comment: You should use `ABC\d{5}?\b` regex if you know that the string format isn't changing. So ABC is hardcoded and then you are finding 5 digits. I have used a word boundary just to ensure that I only pick ABC00000 format strings.

Comment: [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx).